# "/\v[\w]+" cannot match every word in Vim

Tags: regular-expression

Target text: "This is a sample text with some words like hello123 and bye456."
I want to match each word in that text.

`/\v[\w]+` in Vim is bad, it can only match every "w". What is wrong?

I have tried other things:

`[\w]+` in online normal regex tool is good.

`/\v(\w)+` is good in Vim.

`/\v[A-Za-z]+` is good in Vim too.

Comment: Don't use "online normal regex tool" for Vim patterns. Use `:help pattern`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vim within the collection operator `[]` the only constructions that are allowed are:

- individual characters (e.g. `a`)
- range of characters (e.g. `a-z`)
- character class (e.g. `[:alnum:]`)
- the escaped character that have a special meaning in collection (i.e. `\-`, `\]`, `\^` and `\\`)
- the standard escaped characters (e.g. `\n`, `\r`)

In particular not characters atoms like `\w`, `\a`, `\d`, ...

Remark: whenever applicable, for performance reason use character atom like `\d`, `\a` or `\w` instead of the corresponding collections.

More information with `:help /[]`

Comment: Thanks for digging this up. I think the complete list of supported backslash codes is found below `:help /\]`, third bullet point.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that what the OP (probably) wants is `\v\w+`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you. I just want to know what is wrong.