# What is the syntax to use character classes inside Vim regex bracket expression?

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, substitute

I did the following tests:

| code | output | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `:echo substitute("s s", '\v[^s]', "<&>", "g")` | `s< >s` | space replaced. All fine |
| `:echo substitute("s s", '\v[^\s]', "<&>", "g")` | `s< >s` | `[^\s]` is the same as `[^s]`! ?? |
| `:echo substitute("s s", '\v[^ \t]', "<&>", "g")` | `<s> <s>` | both s replaced |

It looks like `\s` does not work inside `[ ]` brackets in Vim regular expression.

Is this expected?

Is there any way I can use `\s \S` inside bracket expressions in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the character `atom` (e.g.: `\s`, `\S`, `\d`, ...) cannot be part of a `collection` (`[]`)

To get the reference in the doc you can look for the `NOTE` in the section: `:help collection`:

```
NOTE: The other backslash codes mentioned above do not work inside []!
```

The following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42728/23502) gives you more details about what is allowed and not allowed in a `collection`.